# How to change default screenshot destination on Fedora

Tags: fedora, screenshot

What I want to do: save screenshots taken with keyboard shortcuts to somewhere other than the 'Pictures' folder, which is the default. Installing additional software is not preferred, but acceptable. Thanks a lot.

System information: Fedora 32 Workstation, Gnome 3.36.5, X11

Edit: on a prompt from a comment, I have attempted to look for readily available solutions. So far, search terms 'change screenshot destination fedora' do not produce usable search results. Some articles do provide instructions for older Gnome versions, but I have not been able to find a solution for my Gnome version. Older versions of Gnome, I believe, use `gnome-screenshot` for screenshots.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? Do you know which application in Fedora handles screenshots?

Comment: I have, of course, searched the Internet for a readily available solution before I asked the question here. Search terms 'change default screenshot destination fedora' yields no usable search results, as you will see if you try it yourself. There are plenty of articles about Windows and macOS, but none about Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

I use Fedora Linux 35 (Workstation Edition), Gnome Version:41.3, Windowing System Wayland:

If you use the `prt sc` button, Fedora automatically saves the screenshot in the Picture folder. In order to have access to such tools you are asking for, you need to open the screenshot application GUI and use it. After you take the screenshot, It will ask you the name and location.

[image: Screenshot GUI]

Here is the popup:

[image: Taken screenshot]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).